# Adding other items to Custom ListBox/ListView and how can user add their own items

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listbox

Trying to learn WPF and it's driving me nuts. So I'm trying to do something like the picture that I posted here. But I can only get the combobox, text, checkbox on top of each other and not side by side... How can I do this?

Also I figured out how to add "text" to the listbox if the user pushes a button, but I need it so that when they add text from a textbox. The combobox, checkbox, and button get added with it. But I have no idea how to do that.

I'm assuming I have to make a class for those things. But how do I do that if I'm coding it in XAML? This WPF is confusing for me.

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="195" Margin="25,345,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="650">
                <ListBoxItem>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="45"> <!--Stacks Items Horizontally-->
                            <ComboBox Width="100" Height="30">
                                <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">DirecTV</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Hyundai</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>None</ComboBoxItem>
                            </ComboBox>
                            <TextBox Width="445" Height="30" Text="Follow RedZone on Twitter" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"></ScaleTransform>
                                </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                            </CheckBox>
                        <Button Content="Delete"  Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: You need a `DataGrid`. Or otherwise define several columns for your ListView. Or otherwise use a `ListBox` and an `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: Yes a grid is the way to go: tutorial here: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid/

Comment: I'm sure Grid works.. but I found that StackPanel works perfectly for I wanted.  But I still am having trouble being able for the (user) to add such a class to my listbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a class to hold the items

```
public class myListBoxRow
{
    public string comboBoxSelection {get;set;}
    public string textBlockText {get;set;}
    public bool checkBoxChecked {get;set;}
}
```

Now define a `ObservableCollection` or `List` somewhere (typically in a ViewModel)

```
public ObservableCollection myListBoxRows<myListBoxRow> {get;set}
```

Then bind the `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource` to your collection

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding myListBoxRows}" .../>
```

To get the controls you want, define an ItemTemplate for your ListBox

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding myListBoxRows}" ...>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding cboItems}" Width="50" SelectedItem="{Binding comboBoxSelection}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding textBlockText}"></TextBlock>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding checkBoxChecked}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Research MVVM in WPF as there are tons of examples of this everywhere. The key part that will tie that together for you is the datatemplate for your listbox/listview

Comment: public ObservableCollection myListBoxRows<myListBoxRow> {get;set}

that line isn't working.  particularly C# doesn't like the get and set part.. any ideas?

Comment: actually it's not recognizing ObserverableColleciton.. though i added using System.Collections.ObjectModel;  i dont get it =\  sorry new to C#

Comment: Did you get it figured out?

Comment: no =( I get what you were trying to say and it makes sense to me...but it's not working.  I'll edit my code in the main, then do you think you can make it work with it?  Somewhere in your code it errors or C# doesn't like it.. particularly i think when I try to create an ObserveableCollection like you suggested.. pretty sure it's just the syntax

Comment: edited the main code to what i have now in xaml.  I'm sure I have to put some bindings in there again and then fix the C#..

Comment: didn't notice you mentioning the datatemplate.. haven't looked into that... but will now.. seems like that's the key to my problem

Comment: your listbox should be about a copy of what I have in my answer, ItemTemplate, DataTemplate...

Comment: can you elaborate more on the C# side (not the xaml) on how to add a new row (with all the checkbox, combobox, etc)?  That's where i'm most confused